# Nested ListView in PyQt5 and QML

Tags: qt, listview, qml, pyqt5

I need to create nested ListView. For example,

```
->Item1
 -->Subitem1
 -->Subitem2
->Item2
 -->Subitem1
```

I have a dictionary data inside Python side. I need to display this data from QML ListView.
So, I should take the model from python and I should design collapsable ListView inside QML. I searched about this but I couldn't find example about it. I tried to create my own model but it didn't work.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off using a [`TreeView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-treeview.html) for this?

Comment: I can use TreeView inside of ListView it doesn't matter but I have difficulty about creating QAbstractModel with pyqt5

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at sections in ListView

https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.11/qml-qtquick-listview.html#section-prop